# How to reference component defined in other .jsx files

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and I'm using it in an [electron](http://electron.atom.io) project. I have component A and B defined in a.jsx and b.jsx separately using the following syntax:

```
  //a.jsx    
  'use babel';
  import React from 'react';
  export class A extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>some text</div>
      );
    }
  }

  //b.jsx   
  'use babel';
  import React from 'react'; 
  export class B extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <A />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

and I render them in the html page:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
var a = require('./a.jsx');
var b = require('./b.jsx');
React.render(React.createElement(b.B, null), document.body);
</script>
```

How could I **reference component A from component B**(e.g. using the A tag in render function of B as illustrated in b.jsx above)? I've tried adding:

```
import A from './a.jsx'
```

but got the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `B`.
```

What is the right way to do it?

The code above can run without error if the reference of component A is removed in b.jsx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good idea to stay away from mixing the new module syntax (`import`, `export`) with the old commonjs style (`require`, `module.exports`).

If your file exports just one component, then you can use a default export.

```
// a.jsx
import React from 'react';

export default class B extends React.Component {

}
```

Then you can reference the class using the import syntax in your main file.

```
import B from './b.jsx';
```

This is basically shorthand for assigning the default export from this module to a new variable `B`.

Alternatively, you can have named exports for modules that export multiple values. This is actually what you had before.

```
export class A extends React.Component {

}
```

This creates a named export called `A` that can be referenced from other files with a destructuring import.

```
import { A } from './a.jsx';
```

If your file only exports one value it's probably a good idea to stick to default exports.

Comment: It works perfectly after I change the export statement to the destructuring form, thanks so much for the thorough explanation and advice of coding convention :]

Comment: I would like to be able to do `./b` without the extension but babel doesnt find the jsx file. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just use a `.js` extension on the file?

Comment: @DanPrince I have a similar problem in ReactJS.net asp net core 3.1 app. Aldo I have followed your instructions and also tryed some permutations, as soon as I use export or import my jsx classes simply are not executed. What am I missing? Except a piece of mind.